# Adding a line at an interval in ChartJS?

Tags: chart.js

I have a chart on my web site that shows user per hour per day, but for ease of reading I'd like to put a line at each new day on the graph.

How do I go about doing this? I just really need a starting point but so far all of my Google searches are to broad.

Thanks in advance,

T.

Comment: I think you can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256695/chart-js-drawing-an-arbitrary-vertical-line

Comment: You can use annotations plugin, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506282/how-to-add-a-horizontal-line-at-a-specific-point-in-chart-js-when-hovering/48517143#48517143, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161695/chartjs-drawing-vertical-line-on-integer-x-axis-value/48165128#48165128